# PostgreSQL: Select entre datas + hora

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7

Bom dia. Na tabela movimento, tenho, além de outros, os campos data e hora. Preciso fazer um select entre a data escolhida e seu dia posterior (Ex.: entre 11/09/2020 e 12/09/2020). Preciso que o select filtre entre as '07:00' do dia 11/09/2020 e as '07:00' do dia 12/09/2020, informando os movimentos de 24 horas.

Entre as datas, informando manualmente, ok:

```
select * from movimento
WHERE '[2020-09-11, 2020-09-12]'::daterange @> data
order by data,hora
```

Contudo queria, tbm, pegar automaticamente o dia posterior ao primeiro dia informado. Além dos filtros de hora. À saber: No sistema, a hora é informada manualmente durante o registro pois pode ser realizado fora do horário atual.

Comment: O PostgreSQL em particular disponibiliza os seguintes valores de datas especiais (date e timestamp): `today`, `tomorrow` e `yesterday` considerando, para timestamp, a hora (00:00).

Comment: Supondo que seus campos data e hora sejam do tipo `date` e `time` use:
`WHERE (data+hora) - INTERVAL '7 HOUR' BETWEEN 'today'::timestamp AND 'tomorrow'::timestamp;`

Comment: Presumi que `data` seja do tipo `date` e `hora` do tipo `time`. Aqui está um teste: `bdteste=# SELECT '2020-09-11 12:00:00'::TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 HOUR' BETWEEN 'today'::timestamp AND 'tomorrow'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)`

Comment: Grato anonimo. Fiz conforme sua sugestão, mas o retorno trás todos os registros. Preciso que apareçam todos os registros entre a data escolhida (11/09/2020) e sua hora (fixada em 07:00:00 da manhã) e seu dia seguinte (12/09/2020 07:00:00). Totalizando 24 horas de movimentos.

Comment: Meu teste funcionou como o esperado: `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('2020-09-09', '10:00'), ('2020-09-10', '03:00'), ('2020-09-11', '12:00'), ('2020-09-12', '05:00'), ('2020-09-12', '18:00')) AS t(data, hora) WHERE (data::DATE + hora::TIME) - INTERVAL '7 HOUR' BETWEEN 'today'::timestamp AND 'tomorrow'::timestamp;
    data    | hora  
------------+-------
 2020-09-11 | 12:00
 2020-09-12 | 05:00
(2 rows)`

Comment: Consegui seguindo a dica do anonimo. Grato pelas informações.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Pelo que entendi, você informa uma data a partira da qual você quer o intervalo de 24h (ou 1) dia após a hora escolhida.

Tente usar o interval:

```sql
select * 
from movimentos
where true 
-- obeservar que o valor da data '2020-09-11 07:00:00' deve vir de alguma variável que é utilizada duas vezes
and (data + hora)::timestamp between '2020-09-11 07:00:00' and ('2020-09-11 07:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 day')
order by
data,
hora
```

Dê uma olhada aqui também. [Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c2ee4/2)

Aqui tem tudo o que o postgresql oferece em relação a isso [Documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html)

PS: Não esqueça de dizer se te atende ou não.

Comment: Grato Marcos.Testei. Contudo ele retorna somente os valores do dia seguinte ao informado...no exemplo que vc forneceu tbm ocorre isto...

Comment: Quero que apareçam todos os registros entre a data escolhida (11/09/2020) e a hora (fixada em 07:00:00 da manhã) e seu dia seguinte (12/09/2020 07:00:00). Totalizando 24 horas de movimentos.

Comment: Editei a resposta para fazer uma correção... Na versão inicial ele estava criando o timestamp no horário 0:0:0. Por isso não aparecia. Uma curiosidade, manter data e hora em colunas separadas é essencial?

Comment: Deu certo Marcos. As colunas precisam ser separadas, infelizmente.. obrigado...